# Learning more about Babel-Relay-Plugin

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay

I've recently started working on a side project whenever I have free time, the side project is a GraphQL Client. I'm making it mostly to learn more about GraphQL. I've got it working and fetching data (Wohoo!). I recently began reading more into Relay and watching talks on it and it seems like it's been maturing so well! What has caught my interest is the `babel-relay-plugin` and I haven't been able to find many articles or talks on it aside from a talk that briefly did a high-level overview of it. I checked out the relay docs and there wasn't much on it. I tried to follow the source but I don't know where to start or where things actually connect with each other.

From what I've been able to piece together:

- You need the graphql `schema.json` for the plugin to understand how to transform the tagged template strings `Relay.QL`.
- The plugin statically analyzes the `Relay.QL` tagged template strings and constructs a query representation based on what it knows from the `schema.json` which I assume is the Immediately-invoked function.

Some of the things I'm trying to understand:

- What information does the plugin extract from schema when reading the `Relay.QL` tagged template string
- How to decide what to generate based on `Relay.QL`.
- How is the generated IIFE able to be sent over the network (It probably isn't, I think The plugin creates a query string from this but not sure how this benefits in performance)

My knowledge on this is really minimal and I probably have huge gaps in my understandings of the `babel-relay-plugin`. But these are some of the things I want to understand further as well as fill in the gaps in my knowledge.